# system-wide setting for php exec() search path

Tags: php, path

I run some PHP websites on a FreeBSD server which was recently updated to PHP 5.2.17, after which `exec("something")` stopped working, and I was required to write `exec("/full/path/something")`.

Since the scripts run on different machines where executables are in different places writing full paths is not acceptable.

Running `passthru("set")` from PHP reveals the PATH variable (for user "www") to be:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I need PATH to point to the PHP safe_mode_exec_dir directory:

```
PATH=/usr/phpsafe_bin
```

Running `putenv("PATH=/usr/phpsafe_bin")` in PHP resolves the problem, but I need a solution that fixes the problem on a global level for all PHP scripts running on this machine, in other words changing php.ini, Apache settings, or other system settings.

Hope someone can provide a good solution to this, maybe even an explanation why this changed in the PHP update. There seems to be no PHP documentation on how the search path for `exec()` and friends is determined.

Comment: Can you simply fix the `PATH` environment variable in your `/etc/rc` before starting Apache? Could you populate a _fixed_ directory `/usr/local/php_bin/` with symlinks to the programs that are scattered all over your servers?

Comment: Please be aware that [safe_mode is deprecated](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php), and you may be well-served by turning it off (and then double-checking all your calls to `exec`... hard-coding path names might not be such a bad idea after all!)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pleasant solution, but it's all I could think of. Create a script file that does the change you've suggested and then use the "auto_prepend_file" in php.ini or .htaccess to include this script. Then in effect every php script that is run will have this file run before it gets executed and thus your directory is changed.

**Caution:** You need to be very careful using this since any errors, extra white space etc in the prepend script can break whole pages, existing features such as download scripts, or any number of unknown effects.

Read More: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php